# Parametric nonlinear programming

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming

I believe, I have a *parametric nonlinear optimization* problem.
The non-convex constraints depend on some parameters, and I seek a solution that satisfies these constraints for all parameters in a specified continuous range.

Let $ {\bf A}(\vec{x},\vec{\theta}) := {\bf A} \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix-valued function of $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{\theta}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ (here $m\ll n$).  Define
$ {\bf L}(\vec{x}):= {\bf L} \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to be a matrix which is a function of $\vec{x}$, and $ \vec{F}(\vec{x}):= \vec{F} $ is a vector-valued function of $\vec{x}$.

**Main problem:**  The goal is to find **any** $\vec{x}$ such that
$$
{\bf A}(\vec{x},\vec{\theta})\vec{y} = \vec{F}(\vec{x}),
\\
{\bf L}(\vec{x})\vec{y}\ge \vec{0},
$$
holds for all $\vec{\theta}$ in some parameter space (ideally, $0<\vec{\theta}<\infty$ or $0<a\le \vec{\theta}\le b$ for scalars $a,b$).

For a fixed $\vec{\theta}$ I am able to solve the problem using nonlinear programming.  I have tried discretizing the parameter space and then solving the resulting coupled nonlinear programs, but this only leads to a solution that is valid for the discrete parameter values.

Is there a better way to think about this problem? Or any standard ways to solve it?  There is no objective function in the formulation I posed above, and I don't know if that is of any significance.

Comment: Looks like the parameter $\theta$ is a scalar - correct?

Comment: In general $\vec{\theta}$ is a vector, however I am open to the case when it is a scalar as well

Comment: First: A problem without objective function is no optimization problem.
Next, the following is important: Are you looking for **any** x that satisfies the constraint or for **all** x? In the first case, you could probably reformulate your problem as optimization problem to find an x that allows 'as many' $\theta$ as possible. The latter case would be harder, I'm not sure there is a way to solve it for general A, F and L

Comment: I am looking for any x that satisfies the constraint for as many $\theta$ as possible.  How would I go about doing this reformulation?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, it is a tricky question. However, one more thing baffels me: For fixed x, are you really expecting eq (1) to hold for multiple $\theta$? That would mean that $Ay$ is independent of $\theta$, at least in a certain range. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Correct - that is on purpose.

Comment: In that case you need to provide more information about A. Is it continuous? differentiable? Isn't it possible to just solve $\dfrac{\partial Ay}{\partial \theta}=0$?

Comment: A is continuously differentiable.  Let me try your suggestion